# Using ArcPy to write Python script with open variables for ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, parameters

I have the following script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\Test"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_to_shape.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

#Variables
shp_input = "hellow.shp"
layer_output = "test"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shp_input,layer_output)
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_output)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_a_shape2.mxd")
del mxd

arcpy.AddMessage("Ended process")
```

As you can see, I have defined variables in the previous script.
However, I need these variables to remain "open" to later transform the script into a sub-tool of a ModelBuilder model.
The need is that apparently having the pre-set variables in the script, wanting to change them as parameters in ModelBuilder does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reviewing the ArcMap help topic on [Integrating scripts within a model](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm):

> Python or other language scripts can be integrated into models by
> making the script into a script tool and adding the script tool to a
> model. This can be used when Python or other scripting language logic
> is needed to enhance a model or to access an external package or
> program from within ArcGIS.
>
> The starting place for integrating scripts within models is the actual
> script. The script must be written in such a way that it can be
> integrated into the geoprocessing framework. For more information,
> refer to [Writing a Python
> script](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/writing-python-scripts.htm).
>
> Once the script is written, a script tool can be created and added to
> a toolbox. This script tool can be added to a model and used to bring
> additional functionality to the model.